Add an account to “Internet Accounts” that require a Yubikey
When adding a new "Internet Account" for a "Microsoft Exchange" work email I need to use a MFA Yubikey.
The current configuration doesn't allow using from an embedded browser, is there any way to force system preferences to use safari and not the embedded browser?


Short answer is probably no. (If your yubikey is PIV then maybe with hardware or software) Does your account work with outlook app? Can you provide a second screen shot showing precisely where you are attempting to enter this information? There may be a different section where you’ll have better success but I can only see the error, now what caused the error to pop over the preference pane.

Outlook (desktop): same behaviour due to using the embedded browser.
Second screenshot: there are no more details really, it's just the embedded browser that happens for the Okta auth.

To add a Microsoft Exchange account on macOS with Yubikey MFA, bypass the embedded browser in System Preferences by using the Microsoft Outlook app instead. Install Outlook from the Mac App Store, go to Preferences -> Accounts, and add your email account there.
This process uses Safari, which supports Yubikey for MFA, ensuring successful account setup.

If that was the case in the past it's no longer valid, outlook also seems to use the embedded browser now.
